# How to change forms with AJAX query?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to realize idea of authorization with code sms.
For example:
 button_1 - i'm getting telephone number from form_1;
 form_2 - another form to enter the code from sms with button_2 which find matches.
 
When I will click on button_1 it will send post query from form_1 and I'm getting needed data. After that AJAX query will change form_1 to form_2 and I can continue authorization with form_2.
 I have bad knowledge about AJAX, but wrote everything what understanding.
 It's don't working. I would be grateful for your help.

```
 $('#but1').on({
   click: function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var val = $("#tel").val(); // Data of form_1

     $.post(<?php SiteController::actionIndex();?>, {tel : val}, function(data){ // SiteController::actionIndex() - check that user with tel is exists and return 1 or false
        if (data == 1) { 
          $('.first').hide();// form_1
          $('.second').show();// form_2 
        } 
     }); 
   }
 });
```

Comment: Provide your ajax you tried.

Comment: You mean about connection? <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>